# How to find the first git commit that's not my commit going back in time?

Tags: git

Is there a way in git to find the first (second, third) git commit that's not my own commit going back in time?

Answer (score 1):

The following commands may prove useful:

```
git shortlog

git log --committer '^(?!YOURAUTHORNAME).*$' --perl-regexp
```

or similarly,

```
git log --author '^(?!YOURAUTHORNAME).*$' --perl-regexp
```

These two variations of *log* use a regular expression to say "not my user."

You can find info on these commands [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html). Obviously replace YOURAUTHORNAME with enough characters of your own username to make it unique. If you absolutely only want the single most recent commit, include the *--max-count=1* argument to the *log* command.

As demonstrated with other answers, there are many ways to produce this, including using other linux tools like *grep* or *sed*.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, not too sure if Git can do this itself, but a bit of help from good old "grep" should do the trick.  Try this:

```
git log | grep "Author:" | grep -v "Author: JohnCrawford" -m 1
```

Obviously put your own name in it and not mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
git log | grep -P -B 1 '^Author:.*<(?!${YOUR_EMAIL})' | head -n 1
```

Replace the string `${YOUR_EMAIL}` with what it should be and you'll get the commit hash of the first commit that doesn't match your email address.

First 3 commits that aren't yours:

```
git log | grep -P -B 1 '^Author:.*<(?!${YOUR_EMAIL})' | grep ^commit | head -n 3
```